# ImportError: cannot import name '__version__' from partially initialized module 'keras' (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

**I have imported the following libraries for my machine learning project but have problem when I try to run my model in the command prompt...**

```
from tensorflow.python.keras import Model

from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Layer, Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Conv2DTranspose, concatenate, Lambda

from tensorflow.python.keras.initializers import TruncatedNormal

from keras.optimizers import Adam

from tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler, CSVLogger, Callback

from tensorflow.python.keras.models import load_model

from tensorflow.python.keras.utils import Sequence
```

This is the error message which I get when trying to run the model in the command prompt.

```
ImportError: cannot import name '__version__' from partially initialized module 'keras' (most likely due to a circular import) (C:\Users\gurun\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\site-packages\keras\__init__.py)
```

Comment: The python script name is adamw_sony.py

Comment: Why are you importing adam from keras, but the rest from tf.keras? That will not work even without the import error.

Comment: do you have a directory in your project named keras? can you post your project directory tree?

Answer (score 2):

It is always recommend to use `tensorflow.keras.*` instead of `tensorflow.python.*`.

This is because anything under `tensorflow.python.*` is private, intended for development only, rather than for public use.

```
import tensorflow as tf
print(tf.__version__)

from tensorflow.keras import Model

from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer, Input, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Conv2DTranspose, concatenate, Lambda

from tensorflow.keras.initializers import TruncatedNormal

from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam

from tensorflow.keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, LearningRateScheduler, CSVLogger, Callback

from tensorflow.keras.models import load_model

from tensorflow.keras.utils import Sequence
```

Output:

```
2.5.0
```

Answer (score 1):

You should be consistent and import keras only from one source and the recommended way, as @TFer2 said, is from `tensorflow.keras` . Your editor maybe can complain that `tensorflow.keras` cannot be resolved but usually that warning can be ignored and all works fine. If not try to uninstall keras and reinstall it accordingly to the version of your `tensorflow` installation.